# SVG rect as its own clipPath

Tags: svg, clip-path

I have some SVG [rectangles](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_rect.asp) with text in them. I would like to avoid the text overshooting the rectangle boundary, so I use a [clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) with the same dimensions as the rectangle:

```xml
<g class="blue">
  <rect x="0" y="20" width="852" height="100"></rect>

  <clipPath id="cp2008">
    <rect x="0" y="20" width="852" height="100"></rect>
  </clipPath>

  <text y="70.5" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" clip-path="url(#cp2008)">
    <tspan x="426">some long</tspan>
    <tspan x="426" dy="1.5em">text</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

This is getting repetitive after a while. Is there a way to shorten the above a bit, e.g., by specifying the `rect` as its own clipPath?

All hints appreciated.

Comment: From your example, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. Have you tried using SVG's [text overflow](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextOverflowProperty) or [auto-wrapping](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextLayoutAuto) features?

Comment: @r3mainer Thanks for the hint! `text-overflow` for SVGs looks nice, but it doesn't seem supported yet. At least http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/css/text-overflow-ellipsis.svg doesn't work on my Chrome 87.

Comment: use a <use> tag instead of one of the rect elements and point the use to the remaining rect